# Android/Kotlin - Selecionar current fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

Em minha action utilizo o método `onBackPressed`. Quando vou comparar o `fragment` que acionou o evento o `Id` nunca é o mesmo e sempre cai no `else`. o que esta errado?

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val fragment = this.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val pressed = fragment?.childFragmentManager.fragments?.get(0) as IOnBackPressed
    var currentFragment = fragment?.childFragmentManager.fragments?.get(0)

    pressed?.onBackPressed()?.takeIf { it }?.let {

        when(currentFragment.id) {
             R.id.embalagemItemFragment -> {
                 // implemetation
             }
            else -> {
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método getFragment para pegar a fragment por meio de uma chave no bundle, segue:

```
supportFragmentManager.getFragment()
```